# Thread safety and piping to streams

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety

If two different threads each try writing one piece of data each to a output stream, is it guaranteed that this operation is thread-safe for `std::string_stream`, `std::cout`, `std::err`, and `std::fstream` (in C++11 onward)? (In other words, are there any guarantees that writing to the same stream from multiple threads won't break the stream or interleave single pieces of data?)

By "one piece of data", I mean "with one call to the pipe operator `<<` using a standard library overload". For example, if one thread writes a string containing a million `0`s in a row, and the other thread writes a string containing a million `1`s in a row, are there any guarantees that there won't be any `0`s mixed with `1`s?

**Code testing this idea:** This code outputs a bunch of `1`s on one thread, and a bunch of `0`s in another thread. I haven't seen any interlacing when piping the output to a file.
I tested this code out in Ubuntu 18.04, using `gcc-7.3.0` and compiling with the flags `-std=c++17 -pthread -O3 main.cc -o main`, and I didn't observe any mixing of `1`s and `0`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

auto now() { 
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
typedef decltype(now()) now_time_t;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::stringstream A {}, B {};
    int count = argc > 1 ? std::stoi(argv[1]) : 1000;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        A << "0";
        B << "1";
    }
    volatile bool waiting = true;
    now_time_t t1_start_time, t2_start_time, t1_end_time, t2_end_time;
    std::thread t1 = std::thread([&] { 
        while(waiting) ;
        t1_start_time = now();
        std::cout << A.rdbuf(); 
        t1_end_time = now();
    });
    std::thread t2 = std::thread([&] { 
        while(waiting) ;
        t2_start_time = now();
        std::cout << B.rdbuf(); 
        t2_end_time = now();
    });
    waiting = false;
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    auto t1_total_time = (t1_end_time - t1_start_time).count();
    auto t2_total_time = (t2_end_time - t2_start_time).count();
    std::cerr << "Time difference: " << (t1_start_time - t2_start_time).count() << std::endl;    
    std::cerr << "t1 total time: " << t1_total_time << std::endl;    
    std::cerr << "t2 total time: " << t2_total_time << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **[iostreams.threadsafety]/1** Concurrent access to a stream object (30.8, 30.9), stream buffer object (30.6), or C Library stream (30.11) by multiple threads may result in a data race (4.7) unless otherwise specified (30.4). [ *Note:* Data races result in undefined behavior (4.7). *—end note* ]
>
> **[iostream.objects.overview]/5** Concurrent access to a synchronized (30.5.3.4) standard iostream object’s formatted and unformatted input (30.7.4.1) and output (30.7.5.1) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result in a data race (4.7). [ *Note:* Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by multiple threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. *—end note* ]

Here "standard iostream object" is one of `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::clog` and the corresponding wide streams (`wcin` et al). Such a stream is synchronized unless `sync_with_stdio(false)` has been previously called on it.

Thus, concurrent writes to `std::cout` et al don't result in a data race, but are allowed to interleave characters. Concurrent writes to any other stream (e.g. string stream, file stream) exhibit undefined behavior by way of a data race.