# Is redirecting std::cout to a std::ofstream still thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cout

I am trying to capture the content written into std::cout stream to redirect it to a text file. For that, I intent to just follow the solution given in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files](https://www.stackoverflow.com/):

```
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to out.txt!

    std::cout << "blabla" << std::endl;  //output to the file out.txt
```

I understand from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout that it is safe for two threads to write at the same time in std::cout. I am fully aware it does not mean that interleaving of text may not happen. My question: is this redirection of std::cout to std::ofstream still thread safe in a multi threading context ? My understanding is that std::ofstream is not thread safe by itself.

I did a test with my own implementation of the std::streambuf injected in std::cout and 5 threads writing on std:cout:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

class StreamToLogRedirector:public
  std::streambuf
{
public:
  StreamToLogRedirector ():
  counter (0)
  {
  }

  std::streamsize
  xsputn (char_type const *s, std::streamsize count)
    override
  {

    counter++;
    if (counter > 1)
      {
    std::cerr << "Counter " << counter << std::endl;
      }
    counter--;
    return count;
  }

  int
  overflow (int c)
    override
  {
    counter++;
    if (counter > 1)
      {
    std::cerr << "Counter " << counter << std::endl;
      }
    counter--;
    return c;
  }

private:
  std::atomic < int >
    counter;
};

int
main ()
{
  StreamToLogRedirector
    redirector;
  std::cout.rdbuf (&redirector);

  auto
    a = std::thread ([](){
             while (true) std::cout << "Write from A\n";}
  );
  auto
    b = std::thread ([](){
             while (true) std::cout << "Write from B\n";}
  );
  auto
    c = std::thread ([](){
             while (true) std::cout << "Write from C\n";}
  );
  auto
    d = std::thread ([](){
             while (true) std::cout << "Write from D\n";}
  );
  auto
    e = std::thread ([](){
             while (true) std::cout << "Write from E\n";}
  );
  a.join ();
  b.join ();
  c.join ();
  d.join ();
  e.join ();

  return 0;
}
```

I can see that the counter is reaching 5, meaning that the functions StreamToLogRedirector are called in parallel.

My conclusion is that the thread safety aspect is not handled at the level of the std::cout object std::ostream, but at the level of the underlying std::streambuf. If std::ofstream is not thread safe, that mean that redirecting std::cout to std::ofstream is now making the usage of std:cout not thread safe by itself.

Is my conclusion correct or I am missing something ?

Thank you,
Simon

Comment: streams are thread_safe, in that outputting from different threads won't break them, but doing so will almost certainly not do what you want

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sorry to be lazy about joining all the thread, I did not do it as I don't care about how the program ends, it does not contribute to my test. But I will correct that as I understand that it is a bad example and can distract the reader. For the increment, I am using an atomic, is it not enough for the point I want to test ?

Comment: @Simon: sorry, my fault. I must have missed atomic. Sorry for my complaints.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Could you elaborate your answer ? My understanding of the std library is that nothing is thread safe unless specified. If the documentation tells about thread safety for the stream like cout/cerr, I see nothing for ofstream about thread safety.

Comment: Research "reentrant" vs "thread safe".

Answer (score 1):

> Is my conclusion correct or I am missing something?

I have come to the same conclusion through very troublesome segfaults.

I did not find the motivation to check this in the source code of libc++/libstdc++. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322839/2191065) corroborates our understanding:

> Thus, concurrent writes to `std::cout` et al don't result in a data race, but are allowed to interleave characters. Concurrent writes to any other stream (e.g. string stream, file stream) exhibit undefined behavior by way of a data race.

What follows is a writeup as to how I ended up here:

---

I tried to redirect `std::cout` and `std::cerr` into a `std::stringstream` for some unit tests with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033102/2191065) for my program, which uses threads. After adding debugging code in those threads that writes to `std::cerr`, I started to see very unexpected segmentation faults from simple lines such as `std::cerr << "test"` or even the `std::stringstream` destructor.

```
Thread 162 "testCLI" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffeea38640 (LWP 2564686)]
0x00007ffff7eb2ac4 in std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#0  0x00007ffff7eb2ac4 in std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7eba88b in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7eacb65 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00005555555d6e3f in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__s=0x555555a87588 "test\n", __out=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:611
```

```
Thread 70 "testCLI" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffefa3a640 (LWP 2572996)]
__pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140737213867584) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44  ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140737213867584) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=140737213867584) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=140737213867584, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007ffff7a83476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#4  0x00007ffff7a697f3 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x00007ffff7aca6f6 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7c1cb8c "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#6  0x00007ffff7ae1d7c in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff7c1f7b0 "double free or corruption (out)") at ./malloc/malloc.c:5664
#7  0x00007ffff7ae3ef0 in _int_free (av=0x7ffff7c5ac80 <main_arena>, p=0x7fffd8201520, have_lock=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4588
#8  0x00007ffff7ae64d3 in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3391
#9  0x00007ffff7eb29f5 in std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007ffff7eba88b in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00007ffff7eacb65 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#12 0x00005555555b2ade in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__s=0x555555a86918 "test", 
    __out=...) at /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:611
```

```
Thread 31 "testCLI" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffef239640 (LWP 2583445)]
_int_free (av=0x7ffff7c5ac80 <main_arena>, p=0x555555b36a90, have_lock=0) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4466
4466    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
#0  _int_free (av=0x7ffff7c5ac80 <main_arena>, p=0x555555b36a90, have_lock=0) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4466
#1  0x00007ffff7ae64d3 in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3391
#2  0x00007ffff7eb1924 in std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

The errors, I saw with the address sanitizer weren't any more helpful. I should have used the thread sanitizer, instead.

```
==2594227==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-3)
    #0 0x7f6986b3e3ff in __interceptor_memcpy ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:827
    #1 0x7f6986a22847 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x14a847)
    #2 0x7f6986a14b64 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x13cb64)
    #3 0x55f13b04e034 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:616
```

These problems fully disappeared after rolling out my own thread-safe `std::streambuf`-derived class. Here is the abridged version:

```cpp
class ThreadSafeStreamBuf:
    public std::stringbuf
{
protected:
    std::streamsize
    xsputn( char_type const* s,
            std::streamsize  count ) override
    {
        const std::scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );
        return std::stringbuf::xsputn( s, count );
    }

    int
    overflow( int c ) override
    {
        const std::scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );
        return std::stringbuf::overflow( c );
    }

    int
    sync() override
    {
        const std::scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );
        return std::stringbuf::sync();
    }

private:
    std::recursive_mutex m_mutex;
};


class Interceptor :
    public ThreadSafeStreamBuf
{
public:
    explicit
    Interceptor( std::ostream& out ) :
        m_out( out ),
        m_rdbuf( m_out.rdbuf( this ) )
    {}

    ~Interceptor()
    {
        close();
    }

    void
    close()
    {
        if ( m_rdbuf != nullptr ) {
            /* Expected to return this and therfore can be ignored. */
            m_out.rdbuf( m_rdbuf );
            m_rdbuf = nullptr;
        }
    }

    Interceptor( const Interceptor& ) = delete;
    Interceptor( Interceptor&& ) = delete;
    Interceptor& operator=( const Interceptor& ) = delete;
    Interceptor& operator=( Interceptor&& ) = delete;

private:
    std::ostream& m_out;
    std::basic_streambuf<char>* m_rdbuf{ nullptr };
};
```

And here is the full code: https://godbolt.org/z/xo7683ahW